# SQL Server update in .NET not working but returning 1 row updated

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have an SQL Server database being updated with an explicit SQL update command using `ExecuteNonQuery()`. However, if the update values match a previous update (e.g. I change a column from 1 to 2, then back to 1, and then back to 2, for the same row), the update does not take place even though `ExecuteNonQuery` returns 1.

I noticed a similar problem with `ExecuteQuery` when two consecutive select statements were identical; I fixed this by setting a variable equal to a unique value and then adding

```
AND the_unique_value = the_unique_value
```

to the select. However, adding this to the update does not work.

Here is the .NET code for the update:

(note `TheValue` and `TheKey` are strings)

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(SomeConnectionString);
conn.Open();
try
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand
    ("update my_table "
     + "set the_value = '" + TheValue + "' "
     + "where the_key = '" + TheKey + "'"
    , conn);
    ReturnValue = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    ReturnValue = -2;
}
conn.Close();
```

This is called three times. Each time, `TheKey` is "1".

The first time, `TheValue` is "1"; `ReturnValue` is set to 1, and the update is successful.

The second time, `TheValue` is "2"; `ReturnValue` is set to 1, and the update is successful.

The third time, `TheValue` is "1" again; the SQL command is now identical to the one used 
the first time. `ReturnValue` is set to 1, but no update takes place.

I could add a column to the table that would hold a dummy value used only to make sure that each update has a different SQL command, but I don't want to modify the table with "unnecessary" data.  Is there another way to get the update to, for lack of a better work for it, "commit" every time?

Comment: So the value is "2" after the third execution?

Comment: Yes, the value in the database is "2" after the third execution.

Comment: For one - you should **never** concatenate together your SQL statements and execute them. This opens up your code to SQL injection attacks. Instead: use **parametrized queries** to provide parameters to your SQL statement; not only does this protect you from SQL injection attacks, it's typically also a lot faster - especially on repeated executions

Comment: **Correction** The problem wasn't with SQL Server at all, but with jQuery; the third .ajax call in the original example was identical to the first one, so jQuery swallowed it and never even called the .NET code, but acted as if it had returned successfully (and the ReturnValue of 1 returned from the second call was still in place).  Apparently, this is a known jQuery "feature" answered elsewhere (I added a dummy parameter to the .NET function being called and assign it a unique time-based value each time).

Answer (score 1):

I would change the sql code to look like...

```
using (SqlConnection  conn = new SqlConnection("My Connection")) //just do a using block here
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    //you should never use string concatination here... ever..
    cmd.CommandText = "update myTable set foo = @foo where bar = @bar";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@foo", "foo");
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@bar", "bar");


    conn.Open();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

The number returned will be one if something matched.  Of course, it will be the same data if the data in the command is the same.

Comment: Is there a way to use a parameter to set more than one value, or do I have to define a separate parameter for each value? 

e.g. something like: 

cmd.CommandText = "update myTable set @updateList where id = @Id"; 

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@updateList", "foo = 'Foo', bar = 'Bar'"); 

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Id); 

For that matter, if there is a way to set more than one value at a time, is it safe, or is that just as bad as string concatenation?

Comment: A parameter can only set one value. so you will need one parameter for each value that you intend to set. When you use parameters you are guarding against SQL injection.  when you use string concatenation you are asking for it

Comment: Understood - but this means I have to hard-code the column names I want to update in the code, since anything other than a string constant would appear to require string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to persist information to the database during a transcation, you have to use the commit command indeed. If you don't commit, the information won't be updated on the database.
You don't need an extra row with extra information for that.

Comment: That's only if you are using a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that SQL Server had nothing to do with it - the problem was, the AJAX call to the .NET function that did the update never actually called the function, but executed the "success" code associated with the call.  Adding a dummy parameter with a unique value to the call fixed it.